# How to tell what files turborepo is using to compute its hash

Tags: turborepo

I am using `turborepo` with remote caching, and sometimes I get a cache miss that I am not expecting.

Can I somehow get `turborepo` to list the files it is using as inputs to its hash function, so I can get more insight into what it thinks has changed?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone arriving here, `--summarize` is what you're after.

relevant docs: https://turbo.build/repo/docs/reference/command-line-reference#--summarize